# What blockchain is suitable for minting SoulBoundToken?

Tags: tokens

I am looking for a blockchain to mint SoulBoundToken.

I would like to use a blockchain called Astar Network. (It's fast and has low GAS costs.) However, I've been told that the Ethereum main chain is more appropriate for this purpose.

I am trying to find out why, but so far I can't find any reason why the Ethereum main chain is more appropriate.

Which blockchain would be suitable for minting SoulBoundToken?

Please let me know with your reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: Polygon would be a great choice. 
I have seen many projects using the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective, a SoulBoundToken is based on a token standard that extends the non-fungible token standard (e.g. ERC721). In words, this non-fungible token standard extension is designed to be soulbound, i.e. non-transferable, meaning tokens of this standard have only one owner throughout the tokens' existence.

To date, there exist several final token standard extensions for the ERC721 with respect to soulbounding. E.g. [ERC5484](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-5484) and [ERC5192](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-5192), and other.

So with respect to your question

> Which blockchain would be suitable for minting SoulBoundToken?

Any blockchain that enables the implementation of a soulbound token standard is suitable for having/minting SoulsBoundTokens.

Many chains support the implementation of different token standards, whereby they differ in their advantages and pitfalls. Its up to you which chain you want to build on. But here are some all-time favorites with respect to popularity (my perspective):

- Ethereum
- Polygon
- Celo
- Binance Smart Chain
- Gnosis Chain
- Avalanche

Comment: Thank you very much.
Great answers helped me solve the problem.